# Why is the state of my NetworkManager changed when I unplug my iphone 4s?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iphone

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
My phone is an iPhone 4s, running iOS 7.0

I never noticed that a mobile device could activate/deactivate the Network status of my computer. Why is this network change happening?

Here is the `/var/log/syslog` when I plug in:
http://photon.logdown.com/posts/285968-syslog-when-plug-iphone-4s-on-ubuntu-1204

Here is the `/var/log/syslog` when I UNplug:
http://photon.logdown.com/posts/285969-syslog-when-unplug-iphone-4s-on-ubuntu-1204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have USB tethering active on your phone. In this case the phone is acting like a network interface; the fact that it's plugged in leads to the creation of a network interface within the system, which, when the phone is unplugged, gets destroyed.

Comment: That would be handful. But, can I really use the interface on iPhone when it's attached? Would that result in two devices(iPhone and Ubuntu computer) using the same interface on iPhone at the same time? Or would iPhone really give up its usage on its own interface?

Comment: @user1203695 Not sure what you mean, but it works like this: when tethering is active, the iPhone, in Ubuntu's perspective, is just a network interface connected through USB, so Ubuntu will take advantage of it, meaning that it will try to fetch internet data through it, much like it would using a, say, ethernet interface, and that's basically it; in the iPhone's perspective, incoming internet traffic will be split between the phone itself and the machine connected to it. Does this address what you were asking?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd like to know, thanks. Further more, does this mean I can use the **2G/3G** network connection from my ubuntu box when iPhone is plugged and using **2G/3G**?

Comment: @user1203695 Yes, that's basically the point of tethering I guess :)